# What is the domain of $\sqrt{\csc(3x)}$?

Tags: calculus

How do you find the domain of a square root of a cosecant, for example $3x$ or $2x$. What are the steps to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Where is $\csc(3x) > 0$? The same place where $\sin(3x) > 0$.  Proceed from there.